# How to reload the current page when form was sent?

Tags: python, django

Hey,
after the form was sent the page needs to be automatically reloaded / refreshed. Either just the current page is going to be reloaded or the variable slug_title (which would be part of the current page url) needs to be passed into the (' ') from HttpResponseRedirect.

Do you have any suggestions? I would really appreciate it. :)

views.py

```py
def posts(request, slug_titel):
    post = get_object_or_404(Thread, slug_titel=slug_titel)
    form = ThreadForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(' ') # <- here I need to put in slug_title from above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [redirect](https://return%20redirect(%27some-view-name%27,%20foo=%27bar%27)) to a view with variables that way:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

return redirect('some-view-name', slug=slug_titel)
```

Comment: Note, redirecting to the same view is perfectly acceptable and gets everything refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the form is valid, you have access to cleaned_data, from there you can fetch the slug value entered by user:

```
if form.is_valid:
    slug = form.cleaned_data.get(“slug_titel”)
    return redirect(“your-view”, slug = slug)
```